# Materialized views and synonyms

Tags: materialized-views, synonym

Can anyone say Materialized view and Synonyms PROS and CONS?

Best regards, Kristaps

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the pros/cons of using a synonym vs. a view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869073/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-using-a-synonym-vs-a-view)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of articles out there:

[Views, Materialized Views and Synonyms](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-views.html)

From SO: [What are the pros/cons of using a synonym vs. a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869073/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-using-a-synonym-vs-a-view)

It depends on what your need is.  The big difference is that the Synonym is simple an alias for the object, which you are not able to filter.

The views allow you to add WHERE clauses and apply column aliases and use expressions for column names.  You also have additional security at the View level that you would not have in a Synonym.