# Difference between "view" and "synonym" in Oracle

Tags: oracle

What is the difference between "view" and "synonym" in Oracle?

This is what I think:

- View can be created using multiple tables. View is logical and does not occupies space.
- Synonym can be created for single table, view, sequence or index. Synonym is physical and  needs space.

Is this correct? If not, then what is it?

Comment: That is not how this site works. If you have a specific question, then ask it.

Comment: @juergen d - please tell me how to make above question more specific. I am new to this site

Comment: @srg20: These are questions where a simple google search would do. If you have a specific program related problem, exception, issues, you may ask here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Table** is a basic unit of data storage in an oracle database. It holds all user accessible data.

**View is a virtual table**

- It can be created on a table or another view.
- It is just like a window through which we can access or change base table data.
- It does not contain data of its own. It always takes data from its base table.
- It is stored as a query in data dictionary. Whenever you query a view it gets data from its based table using this query.

Main advantage of using views are

- You can restrict access to predetermined set of rows and columns of a table
- You can hide complexity of query
- You can hide complexity of calculation

**Synonym is alternate name** given to table, view, sequence or program unit.

- It is used to mask real name and owner of the object.
- You can provide public access to tables by creating public synonyms.

Reference : [here](http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/11291-difference-between-table-view-and-synonym.html)

Other already answered similar questions and references.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/869124/3492139
- https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006020105719

Comment: On view, I think it should be "It does **not** contain data of its own.".

Answer (score 1):

View:

view is a sub set of table.
View is created multiple Tables and to Reduced Query complexity.
View contain Select statement and using filter Commands.

Syonynm:

Synonym is mirror of table.
Synonym created single table and to reduced Table name complexity. 
Synonym doesn't Contain Select Statement.

Answer (score 1):

A view is logical table that is based on table or View. We can create a view to reduce complexity of the query.
A Synonym is alternative name for database objects Like a Table, View, Sequence. It can be Public and Private.