# Materialized view in same DB

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Is there any sense in creating materialized views from one schema to another in same database ? Will a public synonym or a simple view suffice? Please suggest

Comment: You can simply access the data like SELECT * FROM schema.table; and not need any additional objects.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about the same as if you ask if it makes sense to have the same table in another schema of the database. If anybody who can access materialized view / table has access to the schema why bother? And even if not I would ask why they have no access to the schema.

Your question: Will a public synonym or a simple view suffice? That said, I also would say yes.

Comment: What is more preferred? Public synonym or a view?

Comment: This is best answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869073/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-using-a-synonym-vs-a-view